# Scope with days period works from the last deploy date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a scope on a booking model, that takes bookings into the current period of 15 days. it works, so, in production, after one day i seen that not works, on the log applies the scope filter from the moment deployment was done.

First, scope looked as this:

```
scope :current_availables, where(date: Date.today..Date.today+14.days )
```

And now the scope looks like this

```
scope :current_availables, where(date: Date.current.beginning_of_day..Date.current+14.days )
```

What is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is from the Rails 3.1.0 documentation:

> Note that scopes defined with scope will be evaluated when they are defined, rather than when they are used. For example, the following would be incorrect:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, where('published_at >= ?', Time.now - 1.week)
end
```

> The example above would be ‘frozen’ to the Time.now value when the Post class was defined, and so the resultant SQL query would always be the same. The correct way to do this would be via a lambda, which will re-evaluate the scope each time it is called:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :recent, lambda { where('published_at >= ?', Time.now - 1.week) }
end
```

So, you can try updating your scope to use a lambda as the second argument instead of just the `where`:

```
scope :current_availables, -> { where(date: Date.current.beginning_of_day..Date.current+14.days) }
```

(Not sure if you can use `->` if not do `lambda`)

You can also use `14.days.from_now` instead of adding the 14 days to `Date.current`.

Comment: i will deploy it Monday and answer Tuesday, thank you!